# Ajax POST request on mobile : cross domain or WS forwarding?

Tags: jquery, ajax, heroku, playframework, amazon-ec2

I have a Play! 2.2 Java server on Heroku generating my form templates and another on EC2 to save infos in DB.

(Dont ask why such an architecture ... my client really want's like that : he wants to deploy easily it's template changes with heroku but he couldn't put all the server and DB on it ).

Well. I thought about an Ajax Cross Domain request to submit the form directly to the EC2 server, but .. this is a mobile website, and I'm not sure Cross Domain is a good idea in this case.

So i'm trying to forward my form submission from play heroku to play ec2 as easily as possible, not having to bind each parameter manually (dynamicform...)

Any advices ?

---

### My mobile app :

- one form to create a "topic"
- another to post a geolocated message in the topic.
- a template to display the topic and a google map.

---

**EDIT : thinking to other solutions**

In other words, I have a fat website on EC2 with obsolete code and a small mobile one on heroku.
The fat one has my user table and some cool features like thread/comments.

I wonder if :

- I merge the small code into the big one (to access those features).
- Or make requests between the two servers with Ajax cross domain to post forms from mobile
- Or if I re-code only what I need on the small one, which could even take really much time than the first features.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds awfully confusing. Having your database on a remote server will probably require you to run on top of SSL (which affects performance). Also having 2 play applications adds to the mambo jambo.

Have you just tried to use RDS as your database, just simply enable SSL and allow access to your heroku app ?

Comment: Well the architecture of the system is not longer such problematic. But to answer your question, the thing was, I didn't want to make the big model pollute my heroku app.

The thing to do was to recode features needed and import user database into this.